# Send post request with data in every row of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I have a pandas dataframe as shown:

```
header
data1
data2
data3
data4
```

I have to send a post request with each row of this dataframe as the data to be sent along with the post request. And record each response in a new column corresponding to the request in that row. How can I do this all at once without iterating through the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that takes some data as it's input and does a post request with the data and returns the response.
Then use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to map all the values to the function.

```
def Post_Function(data):
    url = "insert your URL here" 
    response = requests.post(url, data = data)
    return response
```

Then you could call the above function like (assuming your dataframe is named "df")

```
df["Response"] = df.apply(Post_Function, axis = 1)
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting this error: ``` ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```. Is this due to some inconsistency in the data?

Comment: yes, you could try printing out the data and its type in the Post_Function to see what is being passed